# Create custom slider jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, carousel, jcarousel

I am trying to create custom carousel with `thumbnails`. I have 2 buttons`(left and right arrows)`, which must simulate clicks on thumbnails. Created this code, but I want to show previous image on the left click, no matter how many times I clicked on the right arrow.

```
var clicks= 0;
$('#rightarrow').on('click', function(){
    clicks += 1;
    $( ".thumbnail").eq(clicks).trigger("click");
})
var leftClicks = $('.thumbnail').length;
    $('#leftarrow').on('click', function(){
    leftClicks -= 1;
    $( ".thumbnail").eq(leftClicks).trigger("click");
})
```

Comment: " I want to decrease elements on the left click" i did not get this

Comment: @darshandave I've just updated my question. Sorry for that

Comment: Hi, check this jquery plugin i wrote : https://github.com/JohnnyBeGood34/JQuery-AnimateSlider it could help you to understand how to do a simple slider

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use the clicks variable instead of leftClicks

```js
    $('#leftarrow').on('click', function(){
    clicks -= 1;
    $( ".thumbnail").eq(clicks).trigger("click");
})
```